# Get MySQL Unique Key Combos

Tags: mysql, database, unique-key

If I have a table created similarly to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    id1Part1 INT NOT NULL,
    id1Part2 INT NOT NULL,

    id2Part1 INT NOT NULL,
    id2Part2 INT NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE KEY (id1Part1, id1Part2),
    UNIQUE KEY (id2Part1, id2Part2)
);
```

how can I now *ask* the database to give me the two "unique key" tuples?
(`SHOW INDEX` doesn't seem to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something like this

```
select
constraint_name,
group_concat(column_name order by ordinal_position) as cols
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where table_schema = 'db_name' and table_name = 'table_name'
group by constraint_name
```

Comment: Hm... I'll try to check it when I get the chance, thanks. Seems like it might be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

mysql can't give you two primary keys. Check this out:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ->     id1Part1 INT NOT NULL,
    ->     id1Part2 INT NOT NULL,
    -> 
    ->     id2Part1 INT NOT NULL,
    ->     id2Part2 INT NOT NULL,
    -> 
    ->     UNIQUE KEY (id1Part1, id1Part2),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY (id2Part1, id2Part2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> desc mytable;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id1Part1 | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id1Part2 | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id2Part1 | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| id2Part2 | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It shows there is only one primary key.

Comment: I'm confused... are we talking about *unique* keys or *primary* keys?